# PHP Download 2 path

Tags: php, mysql, download

I have script PHP download 2 path, 
And i try in localhost this code work, but i try in my server error not work

This Error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pm_mobile_indosat\link.php on line 10

Full Code

```
    <?php

include "conection.php";


$id = $_GET['id'];

$data  = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id = '$id'"));

$paths = [
    "Attachment/".$data['task_id']."/",
    "D:/ALL BACKUP GOES HERE/Attachment_kt_fri_jpg_dll/".$data['task_id']."/"
];

foreach ($paths as $path) {
    if (file_exists($path . $data['attachment_file'])) {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $data['attachment_file']);

        print file_get_contents($path . $data['attachment_file']);
        exit;
    }
}

echo "File not found";
exit;


?>
```

This Error in

```
$paths = [
"Attachment/".$data['task_id']."/",
"D:/ALL BACKUP GOES HERE/Attachment_kt_fri_jpg_dll/".$data['task_id']."/" ];
```

Because i have script if disk C full, then files in disk C cut to Disk D. 
So i want this script work in my Server.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?
`$_GET` values **NEVER** go directly into a query string. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is using the short form of the array declaration introduced in PHP 5.4.

With PHP 5.4 you can declare an array like this:

```
$arr = [];  // for 5.3 you'd use $arr = array();
```

if your code works on one server but throws this error on another, you have a version of PHP less than 5.4 on the failing server.

Either: upgrade the server to PHP 5.4 or later; or edit the code to use the older form of the array declaration.

NB - there may be other incompatibilities between the code and earlier versions of PHP. Upgrading your server is the way to go.